# Reading in a .dic file in Python

Tags: python, encoding

I have a French dictionary file which I got from WinEdt.org [(Zip File)](http://www.winedt.org/Dict/fr.zip). I'd like to read this file into memory, but when I do I get the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in
  position 69: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've also tried using the `codecs` module with the encoding `utf-8`, but that doesn't work either:

```
    with codecs.open(self.template_folder_path + "/" + self.test_language + ".txt",
                     'rb', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
        word_list = []

        for line in fp:
            word_list.append(line.strip())

        self.words[self.test_language] = word_list
```

How can I read this file? I also need to read in a few other dictionary files from that website. How do I go about that?

Comment: When you say "that doesn't work either", what do you mean? Can you show the actual code that's opening the file?

Comment: show some code so we can know where is the problem...

Comment: Try using `latin-1` as encoding because `0xe2` is not a valid utf8 and `print '\xe2'.decode('latin-1')` give `â` ...

Comment: @mouad: Why do you recommend `latin1` in the face of the evidence?

Comment: @JohnMachin: Very nice answer and analyze, and please forgive my ignorance, +1 by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**latin1 aka ISO-8859-1 is "a snare and a delusion".** Decoding random binary gibberish with `latin1` "works", because the `latin1` codec maps all 256 bytes to a Unicode codepoint.

In this case given the information (1) French (2) "WinEdt.org" (hello hello, that's "Win" as in "Windows"). the file is likely to be encoded in `cp1252`.

```
>>> guff = open('fr.dic', 'rb').read()
>>> z = guff.decode('latin1')
>>> sum((128 <= ord(c) < 160) for c in z) # count the C1 control characters
141 
>>> aliens = set(c for c in z if 128 <= ord(c) < 160)
>>> aliens
set([u'\x9c'])
>>> from unicodedata import name
>>> name(u'\x9c')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: no such name
>>> name('\x9c'.decode('cp1252'))
'LATIN SMALL LIGATURE OE'

QED
```

Update: You asked about other files on that website. The first thing to do would be (as the site recommends) to read the .TXT file associated with the dictionary. For example, the large Russian dictionary's .TXT file says "The dictionary assumes standard Windows Russian codepage (1251)". Failing that, try the most appropriate from this list:

cp1250 eastern European Latin-based scripts e.g. Polish, Czech, Serbian (Latin script)
cp1251 Cyrillic-based scripts e.g. Russian, Ukrainian, Serbian (Cyrillic script)
cp1252 western European Latin-based scripts e.g. German, French
cp1253 Greek
cp1254 Turkish
cp1255 Hebrew
cp1256 Arabic
cp1257 Estonian, Latvian and Lithuanian
cp1258 Vietnamese

Comment: Decoding the text with latin-1 seems to give recognizable french words. So does cp1252. Why does it matter which one I use?

Comment: @AlexBliskovsky: If you use `latin1`, words containing "LATIN SMALL LIGATURE OE" will be stuffed up. For other languages, if you use ISO-8859-m instead the appropriate cp125n, the consequences will be far worse. Get into the right habit NOW.

Comment: @AlexBliskovsky: ... common words like œil ("eye") and œuf ("egg")